# Check if string is in CSV and display the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

I am new to python and would like to write a simple script to facilitate my work.

I have an Excel csv file with 4 columns and all are strings:

```
License Number, Product Name, Product Code, Product Origin
```

I want to do the following:

1. Prompt for `Product Code` input.
2. Search the csv file and see if it can find a matched `Product Code` in the csv file.
3. If a match is found then display all the 4 values of the `Product`.
4. If not found, then display a "Product not found" message.

Comment: Great! So do you have a question?

Comment: Pandas' documentation on [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [indexing and selecting data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any code in your question, I won't be providing much of it in my answer—just an outline of how to do what you want:

1. Set `found = False`.
2. Open CSV file for reading.
3. Create `csv.reader` object from open file.
4. Read each row of CSV file using `csv.reader` object.
5. If  `row[2]` (third item) is equal to the `Product Code` entered by the user, then print out the entire `row` *and* set `found = True`.
6. Following completion of row reading loop, check the value of `found` to determine whether or not to display the "Product not found" message after the entire file has been processed.

Comment: I wrote the script and have encounter the error message "PS C:\Users\> python cnum.py
  File "cnum.py", line 15
    print row
            ^
TabError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Comment: Here's the script:

Comment: import csv
import sys

#input number you want to search
number = raw_input('Enter number to find\n')

#read csv, and split on "," the line
csv_file = csv.reader(open('MSDN.csv', "rb"), delimiter=",")

#loop through csv list
for row in csv_file:
    #if current rows 3rd value is equal to input, print that row
    if number == row[2]:
  #print row
 print row

Comment: @Ed: The missing parentheses error is because you're using Python 3 and `print()` is function (unlike it was in Python 2). Also, please edit and add the code in your last comment to your question,